# Pegar Todos os Registros e Separar por Status

Tags: php, laravel

### Dealer.php

```
class Dealer extends Model
{

    # Relacionamento com Medalhas
    public function dealer_medalhas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\DealerMedal', 'id_concessionaria');
    }
}
```

### DealerMedal.php

```
class DealerMedal extends Model
{
    # Relacionamento com Medalhas
    public function dealer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dealer');
    }
}
```

Tenho um relacionamento que estou fazendo no Laravel.
Essa consulta traz todas as medalhas que uma loja tem. Mas eu quero trazer também as medalhas que a loja não tem na mesma consulta.

E separar por status, tipo:

LOJA 1 --- MEDALHA 1 --- TEM 
LOJA 1 --- MEDALHA 2 --- TEM 
LOJA 1 --- MEDALHA 3 --- NÃO TEM

Do jeito que está a última linha não vem, por causa do relacionamento.

Quero que todas venham.

A consulta:

```
# Pesquisar na Base de Dados a Consulta do Usuário
$consulta       = Dealer::whereIdMarca($codMarca)
                  ->whereIdCidade($codCidade)
                  ->where('concessionaria', 'like', '%'.$concessionaria.'%')
                  ->whereStatus(1)
                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensando rapidamente aqui, consigo fazer isso separando em duas consultas.

```
$dealer = Dealer::find($id);

$medalhas_que_tem = $dealer->dealer_medalhas()->get();

$medalhas_nao_tem = DealerMedals::whereDoesntHave('dealer', function ($query) use($id)
{
      $query->where('id', '=', $id);

})->get();
```

O método `get` retorna o método `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, que por sua vez possui o método merge.

Se precisar dos dois resultados unidos, poderá fazer.

```
$dealers = $medalhas_nao_tem->merge($medalhas_que_tem);
```

Comment: Vou cabecear amanhã. Testar está doendo muito ultimamente.

Comment: Dessa maneira não vai funcionar porquê eu não sei o ID do Dealer no momento. Eu tenho uma consulta baseada num **like**.

Comment: Existe esse comando mesmo: **whereDoesntHave** ?

Comment: É possível levar a coluna ID ou uma variável que tem o valor do ID para  o Model ?

Comment: Só se a consulta já tiver sido realizada. Até dentro de um método não estático no model você usa `$this->getAttribute('id')`

Comment: Ele está montando a consulta quase certa. `select * from medals where **medals.id = 1** and medals.dealer_id is not null and id not in (select id from dealer_medals where id_concessionaria = 1)`. Essa parte entre ** aparece automaticamente, não queria que ela aparecesse.

Comment: Essa consulta é usada pelo `Laravel`. Ou você aceita isso ou vai ter que ficar refazendo trabalho na mão.

Comment: Entendi. É que está difícil fazer isso sem colocar o SELECT na view.

Comment: Baseado na pergunta, não toda em si, sua resposta é a mais correta, pois ensina a resgatar dados relacionados e não relacionados. Portanto, vou marcar como a resposta correta. Embora eu tenha solucionado de outra maneira, a maneira que solucionei não responde a pergunta que fiz.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim, na lógica mesmo.

```
@foreach($res->dealer_medalhas as $item => $key)
    <?php 
        $arrM['id'][$key->medalhas->id]      = $key->medalhas->id;
        $arrM['medalha'][$key->medalhas->id] = $key->medalhas->medalha;
        $arrM['icon'][$key->medalhas->id]    = $key->medalhas->icon;
    ?>
@endforeach
<?php unset($medalhas[0]); ?>
@foreach($medalhas as $foo => $bar)
    @if(in_array($foo, $arrM['id']))
        <div class="badges" data-order="1" data-medalha="{!! $arrM['id'][$foo] !!}">
            {!! Html::image('images/medalhas/'.$arrM['icon'][$foo].'-on.png', $arrM['medalha'][$foo]) !!}
        </div>
    @else
        <?php 
            if($foo == 1)     $icon = 'medalha-melhor-preco-off.png';
            elseif($foo == 2) $icon = 'medalha-melhor-atendimento-off.png';
            elseif($foo == 3) $icon = 'medalha-melhor-servico-off.png';
        ?>
        <div class="badges" data-order="0" data-medalha="{!! $foo !!}">
            {!! Html::image('images/medalhas/'.$icon, $bar) !!}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @WallaceMaxters será que pode dar problema de performance ?

Comment: Pelo menos o SELECT não está na View.